# Python BeautifulSoup crawling multiple produtcs from an online shop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Let's say I want to crawl this site: `https://www.alibaba.com/consumer-electronics/action-sports-camera/p44_p201340102?spm=a2700.8293689.HomeLeftCategory.d201340102.2f9a67afhxyQdZ`

Is it possible to open the first product, crawl e.g. the title, price, and picture then return to the overview page and do the same with the next product until I got every product covered?

Comment: Why not? Start by collecting the link to every product on this page. Once you've got it, iterate through every link (means every product)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is very much simple. All the links in the page are loaded only when you scroll down, so you have to use `selenium` to scroll until the end of the page. Once you have scrolled to the end of the page, you have to get the website's html code by using `driver.page_source` and have to parse it using `BeautifulSoup` in order to extract all links. Here is how you do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.alibaba.com/consumer-electronics/action-sports-camera/p44_p201340102?spm=a2700.8293689.HomeLeftCategory.d201340102.2f9a67afhxyQdZ')
lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
match=False
while(match==False):
        lastCount = lenOfPage
        time.sleep(1)
        lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        if lastCount==lenOfPage:
            match=True
time.sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div_tags = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "grid-col-item")

links = []

for div in div_tags:
    links.append(div.div.a['href'])

print(links)
```

Output:

```
['//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2020-Full-HD-4k-1080P-go_62556989288.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Followsun-50-in-1-Accessories-for_62065838705.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Factory-lowest-Price-720p-action-camera_60828536337.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-Product-2-0-Inch-Ltps_62394746927.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Waterproof-full-hd-1080p-720p-sport_1600084796811.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2020-Full-HD-1080P-Go-pro_62555774741.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/A7-Action-Camera-4k-HD720P-Sports_62255736516.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Sports-Camera-4K-Action-Camera-Ultra_62504138600.html', '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2016-Hot-sale-Xiaomi-Yi-Action_60434045578.html' ... '//www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Promotion-item-wide-angle-action-camera_60819668707.html']
```

**Edit:**

Here is the code for the actual website that you want to scrape:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://video.xortec.de/search?sSearch=hikvision&p=1&o=1&n=24%22').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html5lib')

a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_ = "product--title")

links = []
for a in a_tags:
    links.append(a['href'])

print(links)
```

Output:

```
['https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2df4220-dx-w/316l', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2td2137-35/py', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2td2137-25/py', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2td2137-15/py', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2td2137-10/py', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2td2137-7/py', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2td2137-4/py', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2td2137-4/v1', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2df8c842ixs-ael-t2', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2df8a442ixs-af/sp-t2', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5432iw-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5425w-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5425iw-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5330w-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5232w-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5232iw-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5225w-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de5225iw-ae-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de4425w-de-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de4225w-de-e', 'https://video.xortec.de/hikvision-ds-2de4215w-de-e']
```

Comment: Ah shit, maybe I gave the wrong example :D I am actually crawling this website: https://video.xortec.de/search?sSearch=hikvision&p=1&o=1&n=24

With your help I was able to crawl every url I need, but somehow I am unable to connect crawling one site with crawling the other ..

Comment: this I my code until now:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://video.xortec.de/search?sSearch=hikvision&p=1&o=1&n=24")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
products = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "product--detail-btn")

links = []

for product in products:
    links.append(product.a['href'])
print(links)

How do I now run through that list to crawl the articles? Seems like my real site is way easier than my example site

Comment: Lol okay...Do you want to scrape the links from all pages? Or only from the first page?

Answer (score 0):

Heres my code again for better visability:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://video.xortec.de/search?sSearch=hikvision&p=1&o=1&n=24")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
products = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "product--detail-btn")

links = []

for product in products:
    links.append(product.a['href'])
print(links)
```

How do I now run through that list to crawl the articles? Seems like my real site is way easier than my example site